# can you make make a function to handle permission denied on zsh like command not found

Tags: zsh

so I am using zsh.   I have a bunch of functions that move me around the place - like if I type "bin" anywhere - I go to ~/bin etc.  I do this by hooking into the command_not_found_handler as so:

```sh
command_not_found_handler() {
   if [ -f ~/bin/marked/$1 ]; then
      directory=$(<~/bin/marked/$1)"
      echo cd \"$directory\" >~/source_function
      return 0
   ...
```

and this works fantastically - anywhere I am, I can just type marker blah - it creates a marker, and from then on anywhere I am, if I type blah it will just go back to that directory I marked.

Except.

I have "." in my path.  *(Yes I know you think I shouldn't do that)*

and if there happens to be a "blah" file in the current directory - instead of going to the command not found handler - it tries to execute that, and its of course not an executable script, so I get "Permission Denied"

Is there any way to trap this permission denied, like I trap the command not found?  It really hits me a lot with the word "scripts" - because I like typing scripts to take me to my personal scripts directory - but every program I write also has a scripts directory in the git repo for scripts related to that repository.

Comment: Based on a quick reading of [the source](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Src/exec.c), I don't see an interception point, but I'll defer to someone who's better at reading the source (or has a creative workaround)

Comment: I'll go ahead and post a "I don't think it's possible" answer in the hopes that I'm either right or will be proven wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from removing `.` from your path (which you don't want to do), I don't see a way to configure zsh to avoid executing (or attempting to execute) files that match the given command in the current directory. zsh has [lots of options](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#Options), but I don't see documentation describing any relevant ones, nor do I see source code support for one.

I make this claim based on reading the source code for zsh's handling in the `execute()` function at https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Src/exec.c. Here, when zsh sees dot (`.`) in the path, it attempts to execute a file by that name in that directory:

```c
    for (pp = path; *pp; pp++)
        if (!(*pp)[0] || ((*pp)[0] == '.' && !(*pp)[1])) {
            ee = zexecve(arg0, argv, newenvp);
            if (isgooderr(ee, *pp))
                eno = ee;
          } else {
            z = buf;
            strucpy(&z, *pp);
            *z++ = '/';
            strcpy(z, arg0);
            ee = zexecve(buf, argv, newenvp);
            if (isgooderr(ee, *pp))
                eno = ee;
        }
```

After that, the `execute()` function reaches the code below and calls `zerr()`, which produces the "permission denied" error message:

```c
if (eno)
    zerr("%e: %s", eno, arg0);
else if (commandnotfound(arg0, args) == 0)
    _realexit();
else
    zerr("command not found: %s", arg0);
```

... and there is no logic in the code to intercept zsh's behavior in that case.

My best suggestion to achieve the desired result is to remove dot (`.`) from your path.

Comment: thanks - my actual "fix" at the moment is just to choose alternate names for the very few things that conflict.  "." in the path is much more important to me.